# Visual Studio 2010 cannot add reference because it cannot connect to SQL server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, assemblies

I'm pretty new to Visual Studio so this might be an easy issue :)

I have created a Visual C# SQL CLR Database project where I have created a Trigger. This trigger is supposed to access an IIS on another machine in the network. In order to do this I found that I needed System.DirectoryServices but when I added this VS complained that I needed an assembly. Then I found that I should run the CREATE ASSEMBLY in the MS SQL SERVER. Did that successfully and successfully added my database as a data connection (Server Explorer -> Data Connections). In the Assemblies subfolder I can see the System.DirectoryServices but cannot reference it from the add reference... (when right-clicking references in the solution explorer). When trying to add a reference I have two tabs: Projects (empty) and SQL Server which gives the following error:

> The connection to the database failed for the following reason: There
>   is no available SQL server connection.
>
> No server references can be added at this time, but you may continue
>   to develop the project.

When I try to add a server connection to either localhost or the machine name of my computer it seems to do nothing (no error but also no server is added in the server explorer).

Comment: Okay so I deleted the project (keeping the single .cs file I had) and created a new project. This time the database existed when creating the project (which it did not the first time). This made it possible to select the database when creating the project (auto-popup asking for the database) and like magic it made the connection :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Solution Explorer, right click on the Project and select 'Properties'. Select 'Database' tab on the right hand side, then browse to your database or insert a connection string.